# Insert pair values of characters in an unordered map within the key value

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, insert, unordered-map

I have been trying to create an unordered map that takes in (x, y) values as the key to look for its corresponding value.

For example) x=-1 y=0 I would get a certain symbol '$'

I have created the following unordered map:

```
static boost::unordered_map<pair<char, char>, char> map;
```

But I am having problems when I try to insert values into the map doing the following:

```
map.insert({ { '-1', '0' }, '$' });
```

It doesn't seem like I am getting a correct map.

Whenever I do the following within the lookup of the map I get this:

```
char temp = map[{'-1','0'}];
```

temp = '0'

Any help will be much appreciated,

Thank you,
Al

Comment: I don't know whether it's the cause of your problem, but `'-1'` is a multi-character constant, with a value that's probably out of range for `char`. If you mean to use the values `-1` and `0`, then remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks that actually fixed the problem, if you answer I will select as correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'-1'` is a multi-character constant, with a value that's probably out of range for `char`. If you mean to use the values `-1` and `0`, then remove the quotes.

For portability, if the values might be negative, you should use a type that's guaranteed to be signed (like `int` or `signed char`). Otherwise, you might get a surprise if you change to a compiler that gives an unsigned `char`.